# Why are rapid Ctrl-Space sequences sometimes handled differently by GNU screen than slow Ctrl-Space?

Tags: gnu-screen, escape-characters, terminal-emulator, control-characters

I have GNU screen configured to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> as the escape character.  This means that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> will send a literal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to the process in the window. Also, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is the mapping for "switch to next window."

So now I have a conundrum.  When I hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and double tap space, that should be doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, and switching to the next window.  Sometimes it does, and sometimes it doesn't.

When I fire up `showkey -a` to see what the window is receiving, when I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> *quickly*, the result seems to be `^[` (the escape character).  But, it's also sent a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to screen itself, so that the next character I type is taken as screen command—making for extreme confusion.

Worst of all, it is not deterministically reproducible.  Sometimes it works consistently (i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> will switch windows no matter *how* fast I type it), and sometimes I have to type it slow or I get the behaviour described above (consistent for several minutes).

**What could be causing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to instead be sending Escape <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>?**

I am using MobaXterm on Windows 10, but GNU screen is actually running on a RHEL 7.5 host that I am logged into via SSH.

Comment: There's no such thing as a `^SPC` character. What character (or sequence of character) does your terminal emulator send upon Ctrl+Space (press Ctrl+V Ctrl+Space outside of screen)? What value to you use as the `escape` setting in `screen`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas In terminals Ctrl-Space typically generates the NUL byte. Not sure about MobaXterm, though.

Comment: I thought `CTRL-@` 0x00 was infact null, it comes before `CTRL-A` 0x01, etc - It was emacs that interprets ^@ as equal ^-SPC for the binding to set-mark, and it's grown from there and I believe @Stéphane Chazelas is correct CTRL-SPC isn't actually an ascii character, but ^-@ ^-A, ^-B, ... was used to be able to enter 0x00-0x1F on an ascii keyboard. @ = 0x40 A = 0x41,

Comment: Yes, `^@` is the usual "control" representation of NUL and it's true many terminals send NUL/^@ upon Ctrl+Space, Ctrl+@, Ctrl+Backtick, where  the Ctrl modifier takes the lowest five bits of the character that would be sent without Ctrl. `screen` for its `escape` command seems to interpret `"^ "` the same as `"^@"` and mean NUL, so it's likely what the OP used, and what the OP's terminal sends.

Comment: When you type Ctrl+Space in sequence outside of screen, do you always see the same characters (presumablly `^@`/NUL)?

Comment: It's unrelated to ***screen***, but from your description a (mis)feature of MobaXterm.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes, ctrl-@ is what I mean.